# How to override external module class with css module pattern in react

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

**I want to override a external module `css`class locally for a component**

**`In my code`**

```
import `style` from './style.module.css' // this is local css module 
import `ExternalComponent` from 'ExternalComponent' // suppose this is external module i'm using 

    function Component(){
        return(
               <ExternalComponent/>
             )
    }
```

Now the `ExternalComponent` render a `div` element with a class `parent`. So if i am importing the
`ExternalComponent` how can i override the `parent` class of `ExternalComponent` in my locally imported `style` module so that the style in the `ExternalComponent` change only for this component
only and else where i'm using it does not change.

**I'm using react by the way.**

Answer (score 1):

**style.module.css**

```
.whatever-name-scope {
  :global {
    .parent {
      // override here
    }
  }
}
```

Then your jsx goes:

```
function Component(){
  return (<div className={style.whateverNameScope}>
    <ExternalComponent/>
  </div>)
}
```

Comment: What does global refer to

Comment: That syntax of style.module.css you showed is showing error

Comment: maybe we are using different flavor of css module syntax. That `:global` is telling the css module to un-suffix the css classname ".parent". Without it, css module system by default output sth like ".parent-2a8fb". I'm not sure which flavor you use, check the doc.